# Adding implementation 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:emotion:1.0.355' in android Studio 3.2 giving error

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

When I try to add implementation 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:emotion:1.0.355' in android Studio 3.2 giving error 
but if I am adding com.microsoft.projectoxford:face:1.4.3 it works fine

The error i got is this:

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\Utkarsh Deepanjan\AndroidStudioProjects\EmotionDetector2\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:11: error: unexpected element <library> found in <manifest>.

Command: C:\Users\Utkarsh Deepanjan\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\012977c8d929b8a8807ee4cd4cfd3235\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Utkarsh Deepanjan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\Utkarsh Deepanjan\AndroidStudioProjects\EmotionDetector2\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\Utkarsh Deepanjan\AndroidStudioProjects\EmotionDetector2\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\Utkarsh Deepanjan\AndroidStudioProjects\EmotionDetector2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\Utkarsh Deepanjan\AndroidStudioProjects\EmotionDetector2\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.utkarshdeepanjan.emotiondetector2\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\Utkarsh Deepanjan\AndroidStudioProjects\EmotionDetector2\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Here is the build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.utkarshdeepanjan.emotiondetector2"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:emotion:1.0.355'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:emotion:1.0.355'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a bug in the AndoridManifest of either that version of the microsoft library or one of its dependencies. It is using the `<library>` tag while the correct one is `<uses-library>`.

What you can do is either stick to the older version of that library until the oweners fix that bug, or, if you really need that library and **you know what you're doing** (can't stress this enough) you can tell AAPT2 to ignore this error by adding this to your build.gradle:

```
android {
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--warn-manifest-validation"
    }
}
```

This will ignore **ALL** unrecognized tags in the merged manifest. This **might** lead  to runtime errors, so plese be careful using this.